# Unable to connect with Github on mac

Tags: github

My mac is not able to connect to GitHub. I have tried pinging GitHub and it returns request timeout. Any suggestions will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems more networking related and not programming related?

Answer (score 0):

I messed up my .gitconfig file a while ago while experimenting with it, so i deleted the file and try to connect with GitHub and it worked.